# Can I write javascript web apps in visual studio 2015?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015

I don't know anything about javascript web programming... but want to learn.

My question is :  Can I use visual studio 2015 to write, debug and publish(?) javascript web applications.

Again... I don't know if 'publishing' is the right terminology for writing web applications in Javascript... of if you can even 'write' web applications in Javascript...

Any information on the topic would be good to know.

thanks

Comment: Yup, I use Visual Studio 2015 at work every day.

Comment: Why don't you try and see

Comment: What do you need to write Javascript? A text editor. Can VS 2015 edit text? … Probably yes.

Comment: Everything in JavaScript can be developed in visual studio

Comment: "Why don't you try and see?" Take this to heart. Programming is great because you can just try things out and you're almost always never worse for wear afterwards. Keep backups of files and don't just run delete or remove commands willy nilly. Other than that, just try things.

Comment: No, you have to use Vim without plugins. There is no other way.

Comment: I think you have go your answer, take down this question

Comment: I really don't understand why my question was "put on hold"... it clearly states "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming"  this question clearly is asking about a tool (visual studio 2015) and it if can be used in Javascript programming... ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Visual Studio to create JavaScript files. It also has tools to publish, depending on the app and environment there are a lot of ways to go about it, and VS can support a lot of them (repositories, FTP, etc).

I recommend just diving in, firing up a blank project and find some tutorials to get you started. JavaScript is probably one of the easiest to develop with (at least getting started) because it has no special needs other than somewhere to write text.